# Upload file and send it to the controller via ajax - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I want to send form parameters to server.

This is my html:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                    <label>Name: *</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Description: *</label>
                    <input type="text" id="description"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Rules: *</label>
                    <input type="text" id="rules"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label/>Select File to Upload: <input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" id="confirm" value="Confirm">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Here's ajax call:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("button#confirm").click(function () {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var description = $("#description").val();
            var rules = $("#rules").val();

            var file = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
            if (file.files.length) {
                var picture = file.files[0];
            }

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("name", name);
            data.append("description", description);
            data.append("rules", rules);
            data.append("picture", picture);


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "/api/forum/addNewForum",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: undefined,
                processData: false,
                data: data
        });
```

And my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("addNewForum")]
    public IHttpActionResult addNewForum()
    {       
        var picture= HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["picture"];      
        return Ok;
    }
```

But I always get null in this line

```
var picture= HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["picture"];
```

The problem is that HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count is always 0.
This is my first time doing something like this. What am I doing wrong? And is there a better way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to make some changes with your code.
Replace your ajax code with below.

```
$("button#confirm").click(function () {

    var data = new FormData($("form")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/forum/addNewForum",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data
    });
});
```

And then try submitting form check what response you get

Comment: When I do that I get this: 
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23 POST http://localhost:65312/api/forum/addNewForum 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: What kind of file do you upload?

Comment: It's just photo. JPG image

Comment: My bad, that message appeared because I had some model as parameter in here: public IHttpActionResult addNewForum() . When its empty that message doesn't show but my Request.Files.Count is still 0. What type should my parameter be? I guess I should have them in order to process data..

Comment: Okay, but how can I get that name, description and picture in my controller? How can I access them?

Comment: I did it. Thank you so much!